# How to get the UITAbleViewCell highlighted state to change the cell background?

Tags: ios, uitableview, background, highlight

I'm trying to change the cell background image when user tap on a cell (highlighted state), I've been trying this way but it's not working:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFONT_NAME size:kFONT_SIZE];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row320x63.png"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row320x63_pressed.png"]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row320x63.png"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listOfMenuSettings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"settings_icon_%d", indexPath.row]];

    UIImageView *pressed = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row320x63_pressed.png"]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:pressed];

    return cell;
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Is the name of image correct?

Comment: I tried out a sample to check this, I needed to set backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView only in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` only. Nothing else. It worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find `setSelectedBackgroundView:` instance method in apple documentation. But there is a property `selectedBackgroundView`.
So try:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = pressed;
```

Comment: `selectedBackgroundView` is a property so it can be set in both ways, there is no difference.

Comment: @IdanMoshe When you select a cell, check by debugging what is set to background property of cell in this method: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ }`

Comment: I'm doing stuff in didSelectRowAtIndexPath so I know didSelectRowAtIndexPath  is not messing up.

Comment: @IdanMoshe I suggested to check so that you come to know whether background is nil or what.